# Batch file to upload all files in directory to FTP

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to make a bat script to upload all files from a folder to an FTP server.

I followed the below guide and manage to get a single file uploaded but can't figure out how to upload everything in the folder.

[How to Automate FTP Uploads from the Windows Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/)

From what I've read I think i need to somehow use the mput command?

At the moment my upload.bat file looks like this:

```
myftp.bat .\logs\test.txt
```

inside myftp.bat is:

```
@echo off
echo user MyUserName> ftpcmd.dat
echo MyPassword>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat MyFTPServer
del ftpcmd.dat
pause
```

Comment: What is in myftp.bat?

Comment: Updated to include myftp.bat

Comment: Are you trying to upload everything in .\logs\ or everything that is listed in .\logs\test.txt? (But yes, you will be using `mput`.)

Comment: All the text files that are in the logs folder

Comment: Get inspired by this [MultipleFileUpload.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782485/ftp-commands-in-a-batch-script-does-not-working-properly)

Comment: Perfect Hackoo!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`mput` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-mput_1) like:

```
cd logs
prompt
mput *
```

Without [`prompt` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-prompt_1), you would get asked to confirm each transfer.

---

Instead of the `prompt` command, you can also use the `-i` switch:

```
ftp -i -n -s:ftpcmd.dat MyFTPServer
```

Comment: He could also use `ftp -n -i -s:ftpcmd.dat MyFTPServer`

Answer (score -1):

You could also make a batch file that runs multiple other hidden batch files so that you can transfer each file with an individual batch file. If you want the code for this, just ask but it looks like the best solution has already been said ^^.